# adding objects to empty array of object

Tags: angular, typescript

The issue at hand is with the Typescript part of an Angular app.

I have a data array I've received from a subscription; it contains several (but not a consistent or predictable number of) objects with members "titleName" and "ID".  I need to add the member "toggle", which will be interacted with within the component.  Due to the database call in question and its other uses, I can't realistically add "toggle" on the services side.
I've tried the following:

```
titlesraw;
titles: any;

...

getTitles() {
   this.getTitles.subscribe(
   data => {
      this.titlesraw = data;
      console.log(this.titlesraw); //console reads what I expect
      for (var i = 0; i < this.titlesraw.length; i++) {
           let title = {
             id: this.titlesraw[i]["ID"];
             titleName: this.titlesraw[i]["titleName"];
             toggle: true;
           }
           console.log(title); //console reads what I expect
           this.titles.push(title);
          }
       }
    )
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at <line with this.titles.push(title)>

I think this is because I'm not declaring `titles` correctly.  What do I need to do differently?

EDIT:  I've changed `titles: any;` to `titles: any[] = [];`, and I get the following error instead:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ID') at <line with this.titles.push(title)>.

Again, when I do the printout of the temporary variable `title`, it shows me *exactly* what I expect.

Comment: You declare `titles` but didn't assign value to it. It should be `titles: any[] = [];`

Comment: And note that titles should be declared as an array like Yong Shun suggested since push is a method of an array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it very easily with `map` function.

Let me explain to you. Here, I am assuming that you are receiving an `array` of `objects` from an `Api` call. You can modify your response using `map` function of `arrays` like this.

```
titles = [];
this.getTitles.subscribe(data => {
  this.titles = data.map((titleObject) => {
    titleObject.toggle = true;
    return titleObject;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all let me point out some good practices while working with TypeScript.

1. Stick to types and avoid using `any`. Check [this article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/typescript-stop-using-any-there-s-a-type-for-that) for better understanding. But basically, when you start using `any` you "...are saying *no thank you* when over 500 contributors to the language offer their help. It sounds like to opt-out of the type checker, and with it, losing all security and confidence in our type system should not be a decision taken lightly." I am not saying you should never use it, even because there will be cases where you are going to need it, so just avoid it, especially in this specific case.
2. Create types/models for your objects.
3. You don't need `titlesraw`, at least in this piece of code that you're showing up.

Based on it and answering your question, the problem is due because `titles` is not of `Array` type. `push` is a method from `Array` type, thus your `titles` should be an `Array` for this to work.

With that said, here's how your code should look like:

```
class Title {
  id: number;
  titleName: string;
  toggle: boolean;
}

titles: Title[] = [];

...

getTitles() {
   this.getTitles.subscribe(data => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
           const title: Title = {
             id: this.data[i]["ID"],
             titleName: this.data[i]["titleName"],
             toggle: true
           }
           this.titles.push(title);
          }
       }
    )
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare this class within a class?  Since this is Angular, this code snippet is within a component class.

Comment: you don't need to declare a class into another class. The recommended approach is that you organize your code into folders that represents its content. For models, for example, you would create a folder called `models` into `src/app` and create a new file called `title.ts` into that folder. Make sure to export your class by using the `export` before the `class`: `export class ... {`